# Hive count(*) returns extra row after INSERT OVERWRITE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm performing an insert overwrite action for hive table.

It looks like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE xyz (partition_date)
SELECT a, b ,c, d
FROM source;
```

After that I'm running a `SELECT COUNT(*)` from this table in order to check its validity but I am getting a wrong value.

My hive table is set with properties `TBLPROPERTIES('hive.compute.query.using.stats'='false');`

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of the output that you are getting that is incorrect?

Comment: how did you validate...

Comment: add `set hive.compute.query.using.stats=false;` in the same session before `SELECT COUNT(*)`, not in the table properties.